# Не срабатывает повторный рендер у дочернего элемента дочернего элемента(не тавтология)

Tags: reactjs, redux

Не срабатывает рендер у дочернего элемента дочернего элемента(не тавтология)
https://gitlab.com/Kir1/redux.git
Ветка two-child
При клике на Todo элемента на зелёную кнопку(вкл, выкл) повторный рендер срабатывает, но при клике на эту эе кнопку у TodoChild элемент меняется в хранилище(что вижно по оставленным мной логам), но повторный рендер не происходит.

Comment: посмотрел Ваш проект. то, что Вы делаете внутри `reducer` - делать нельзя, а именно использовать Ваши вспомогательные функции из **helpers**. это антипаттерн. используйте для этого `middleWare` и только. и вообще у вас редъюсер при `action`  **SHOW_FORM** ничего не меняет в `store`. зачем он тогда там?
к сожалению, там много чего нужно исправить

Comment: Он меняет, он заменяет весь список, благодоря чему меняются кнопки вкл/выкл у Todo. Но проблема в ChildTodo, в хранилище он его меняет, но повторный рендер Todo и соответсвенно ChildTodo не происходит,
хотя Todos рендер происходит, в этом проблема.

Comment: case SHOW_FORM: {
            let todos = [...state.todos];
            changeElement(todos, action.id, undefined, (result) => {
                let element = {...result.element};
                if (element) element.showX = !element.showX;
                console.log(element, 'finded element');
                return element;
            });
            return {...state, todos};

Comment: В общем, пока что решил так, что в цикле в свойство todo помещается не ссылка на объект, а клонированный объект, то бишь <Todo key={index} todo={{...todo}} index={index}/>

Comment: В последнем коммите решил проблему через ownProps в mapStateToProps